# dart/flutter: Variable wrapped in ValueNotifier doesn't update

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I am creating a translation app in Flutter. I have created a class `CurrentLanguages` in a file `currentLang.dart`.

```dart
// currentLang.dart

import 'package:vtranslate/models/lang.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CurrentLanguages extends ChangeNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<Lang> sourceLang =
      ValueNotifier<Lang>(Lang('English', 'en', false));
  ValueNotifier<Lang> outputLang =
      ValueNotifier<Lang>(Lang('French', 'fr', false));

  changeSource(Lang language) {
    sourceLang.value = language;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changeOutput(Lang language) {
    outputLang.value = language;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

In another screen, `language-pages.dart`, I have a custom list element which has an `onSelect` function which calls a function `_sendBackLanguage`. This function takes a parameter of language and sets the value of the sourceLang/outputLang using the functions `changeSource()` and `changeOutput()`

However, if we print the values of `CurrentLanguages().sourceLang.value.name` (same with outputLang) => the variable does not update and the same content shows as it was before the changeSource/changeOutput function was called (i.e., English and French)

```dart
// language-pages.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vtranslate/components/lang-list-element.dart';
import 'package:vtranslate/models/lang.dart';
import 'package:vtranslate/helper/currentLang.dart';

class LangPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LangPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<LangPage> createState() => _LangPageState();
}

class _LangPageState extends State<LangPage> {
  final List<Lang> _langList = [
    Lang('Afrikaans', 'af', false),
    Lang('Arabic', 'ar', false),
    Lang('Belarusian', 'be', false),
    Lang('Bulgarian', 'bg', false),
    Lang('Bengali', 'bn', false),
    Lang('Catalan', 'ca', false),
    Lang('Czech', 'cs', false),
    Lang('Welsh', 'cy', false),
    Lang('Danish', 'da', false),
    Lang('German', 'de', false),
    Lang('Greek', 'el', false),
    Lang('English', 'en', false),
    Lang('Esperanto', 'eo', false),
    Lang('Spanish', 'es', false),
    Lang('Estonian', 'et', false),
    Lang('Persian', 'fa', false),
    Lang('Finnish', 'fi', false),
    Lang('French', 'fr', false),
    Lang('Irish', 'ga', false),
    Lang('Galician', 'ga', false),
    Lang('Gujarati', 'gu', false),
    Lang('Hebrew', 'he', false),
    Lang('Hindi', 'hi', false),
    Lang('Croatian', 'hr', false),
    Lang('Haitian', 'ht', false),
    Lang('Hungarian', 'hu', false),
    Lang('Indonesian', 'id', false),
    Lang('Icelandic', 'is', false),
    Lang('Italian', 'it', false),
    Lang('Japanese', 'ja', false),
    Lang('Georgian', 'ka', false),
    Lang('Kannada', 'kn', false),
    Lang('Korean', 'ko', false),
    Lang('Lithuanian', 'lt', false),
    Lang('Latvian', 'lv', false),
    Lang('Macedonian', 'mk', false),
    Lang('Marathi', 'mr', false),
    Lang('Malay', 'ms', false),
    Lang('Maltese', 'mt', false),
    Lang('Dutch', 'nl', false),
    Lang('Norwegian', 'no', false),
    Lang('Polish', 'pl', false),
    Lang('Portuguese', 'pt', false),
    Lang('Romanian', 'ro', false),
    Lang('Russian', 'ru', false),
    Lang('Slovak', 'sk', false),
    Lang('Slovenian', 'sl', false),
    Lang('Albanian', 'sq', false),
    Lang('Swedish', 'sv', false),
    Lang('Swahili', 'sw', false),
    Lang('Tamil', 'ta', false),
    Lang('Telugu', 'te', false),
    Lang('Thai', 'th', false),
    Lang('Tagalog', 'tl', false),
    Lang('Turkish', 'tr', false),
    Lang('Ukranian', 'uk', false),
    Lang('Urdu', 'ur', false),
    Lang('Vietnamese', 'vi', false),
    Lang('Chinese', 'zh', false),
  ];

  _sendBackLanguage(Lang returnedLanguage) {
    // if (this.widget.title == "Source Language") {
    //   setState(() {
    //     CurrentLanguages.sourceLang = returnedLanguage;
    //   });
    // } else if (this.widget.title == "Translation Language") {
    //   setState(() {
    //     CurrentLanguages.outputLang = returnedLanguage;
    //   });
    // } else {
    //   throw Error();
    // }

    if (this.widget.title == "Source Language") {
      CurrentLanguages().changeSource(returnedLanguage);
    } else if (this.widget.title == "Translation Language") {
      CurrentLanguages().changeOutput(returnedLanguage);
    } else {
      throw Error();
    }

    Navigator.pop(context);
    print(CurrentLanguages().sourceLang.value.name);
    print(CurrentLanguages().outputLang.value.name);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        itemCount: _langList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return LangListElement(
              language: _langList[index], onSelect: _sendBackLanguage);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please advise on what error I have made as this is one of my first few apps.

Full source code can be found here in the DEV branch: https://github.com/AaravHattangadi/vTranslate/tree/dev

Comment: Everytime you call `CurrentLanguages()` you are creating a new instance

Comment: @Ivo Thanks for pointing that out - however, accessing the variables using `CurrentLanguages.sourceLang.value` gives an error `Instance member 'sourceLang' can't be accessed using static access`

Comment: Because that's not how you are supposed to use it. I'd suggest you to read https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: @Ivo Thanks for that - I've fixed the variable updation problem now - I just needed to make the variable in CurrentLanguages() class a static variable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my errors by making the variables in the CurrentLanguages class static. Thanks Ivo.

```dart
import 'package:vtranslate/models/lang.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CurrentLanguages extends ChangeNotifier {
  static ValueNotifier<Lang> sourceLang =
      ValueNotifier<Lang>(Lang('English', 'en', false));
  static ValueNotifier<Lang> outputLang =
      ValueNotifier<Lang>(Lang('French', 'fr', false));

  changeSource(Lang language) {
    sourceLang.value = language;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changeOutput(Lang language) {
    outputLang.value = language;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```